# graphic driver for intel core 2 duo T5250

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I have installed UBUNTU 12.04 LTS on compaq presario but it is not showing the graphics as good as windows xp.my system configuration is-

```
**description: Notebook
product: Presario C700 Notebook PC
vendor: Hewlett-Packard
version: F.34
width: 32 bits
capabilities: smp-1.4 smp
configuration: 
*-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: 30D9
   vendor: Hewlett-Packard
   physical id: 0
   version: 83.21
   slot: Base Board Chassis Location
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: Hewlett-Packard
      physical id: 0
      version: F.34
      date: 09/25/2008
      size: 1MiB
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5250  @ 1.50GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: e
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: 6.15.13
      serial: 0000-06FD-0000-0000-0000-0000
      slot: CPU
      size: 1500MHz
      capacity: 1500MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 667MHz**
```

Plz any one help me as display is not pleasing!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and upload it somewhere and then edit your post with a link to that screenshot? I know you can't post pictures here yet, but having a screenshot as to what the graphics look like would help a lot, as there can be any number of issue related to graphics. Also, when you say the graphics are not pleasing to look at, what do you mean? Are they corrupted/glitchy or just low resolution?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness yes,it's low resiluation prob

Comment: Okay. This is pretty common issue. Can you run `lspci | grep VGA` and edit your question with the result of that? It would help us a lot.

Comment: Command's result:-  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03)

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel` and tell me what happens.

Comment: some pkg removed and some installed but seems no changes in graphics

Comment: Did you reboot? Try rebooting and see how the graphics are doing.

Comment: it's look good after installing but mouse double-click is gone.i have to do it using left button.any suggetion why it is so?

Comment: Hmm. That's strange, and I don't think that's something that installing new graphics drivers would cause. Try going into **System Settings**, then **Mouse & Trackpad**, and seeing if any of the settings are off.

Comment: no. every thing is On.

Comment: I think that might be a separate question then, you can mark this one as answered and make a new one. Have you installed any other software recently? Also, try moving the double-click slider back and forth and test it out and see if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this issue in the comments, turns out all the OP needed to do was install the Intel Xorg drivers via `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`.

However, with the reboot the OP's double-click is messed up, so that's still be resolved (most likely will require a new question).