# Graphics Messed up after updating Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, intel-graphics

I installed Lubuntu on an old laptop. Everything was fine until I installed updates the other day. After the updates, the graphics were messed up. The menu and the bar at the bottom of the screen are ok. Also, if I open a terminal, that is clear too. I'm about to just reinstall everything but wanted to ask here first.

Link to picture: https://photos.app.goo.gl/cDo9qkJsCfSpHtUQA

I am really not good with computers, but here is the hardware info:

```
Toshiba Satellite C655
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
5.4.0-77-generic
Pentium(R) Dual_core CPU T4500 @ 2.30GHz
MemTotal: 3897504 kB

Graphics: Device-1: Intel Mobile 4 Series Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
          Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz
          OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Mobile Intel GM45 Express (CTG)
          v: 2.1 Mesa 21.2.0-devel (git-7de5293 2021-07-18 focal-oibaf-ppa)
```

If there is some other hardware info I need, I know how to type in the terminal.

cat /sys/devices/cpu/caps/pmu_name: core2

Comment: Please edit the question and add hardware specifications, other than "old laptop" and also the Lubuntu release.

Comment: You didn't provide release details; which give us details as to your software stack (more clues).  I would **not** re-install; but at `grub` (ie. the boot loader that should appear on boot before you see the Lubuntu `plymouth` screen/graphic)  At this I'd use the *Advanced Options* to boot using an older kernel where the issue shouldn't occur I believe... That will provide clues but I'd want your *unstated* release details before I gave more (I'd also consider filing a bug as it sounds like a regression (https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/bugs/ with bug likely filed on `linux` but I'm guessing)

Comment: fyi:  the `grub` menu is briefly discussed in this page on the menu (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/A/tips_and_tricks.html?highlight=grub), also note as I don't know your release I've provided the latest *stable* link to the manual (change *stable* in the URL to say *lts* if you're using 20.04)   also fyi: when I said guessing it's *linux*; I'd normally `sudo lshw -V video` to confirm what kernel module (driver) your using & use that to adjust; but `ubuntu-bug linux` will likely suffice....

Comment: How did you install the mesa stuff?  I think toshiba c655 uses Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 3000 and not GM45 Express but I could be wrong.

Comment: I don't know if I did install the mesa stuff. At one point, I was attempting to install Java Minecraft which did not go so well. Either it supports the mesa out-of-the-box or perhaps I did something trying to get Minecraft to work. Honestly, I don't even know what mesa is.

Comment: Also, is `i965-va-driver-shaders` installed? Check `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install i965-va-driver-shaders` and then reboot. Additionally, I'll try to see if I can find some info on the GM45 thing. I had a c655 but swapped the CPU out for an i3 so that might be why it's different.

Comment: Okay, I found some info. Please run the following command and include the output in your question. Thanks. `cat /sys/devices/cpu/caps/pmu_name` This should report something like "sandybridge" or something else.

Comment: Okay, that is probably why it's GM45 so that's okay. According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/578446/167115) they a fixed similar graphics issue by installing `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel` and reboot to apply the changes.

Comment: Please let me know if that fixes your issue. If so, I will mark this as a duplicate. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, the sudo apt insall xserver-xorg-video-intel did not fix the problem.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to try google chrome and [disable hardware acceleration](https://askubuntu.com/a/679282/167115) to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: You are using 3rd party drivers (oibaf) which I know little about (except they prevent *release-upgrade* in the future) so I'd look there. Your issue is not a Ubuntu bug, but related I suspect to the 3rd party drivers.

Comment: I want to thank everyone for their help. I fixed the problem. The following commands fixed it: sudo apt install ppa-purge and then: sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

Comment: Please write your 'answer' in the answer section below.  You can then (*in a few hours*) accept the answer as the answer and grain some *reputation* (*assuming you don't like another offered answer better*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphics problem caused by using 3rd party drivers (oibaf). The following fixed the problem:

```
$ sudo apt install ppa-purge
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
Reboot
```